# rquirejs - getting issue from global space

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In my app, I created a global space for my app saying `socialApp`. even before i call the initialize method, I am declaring the `socialApp` in the window like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'scripts/appRoutes',
    'scripts/app/appModel',
    'scripts/app/layout/appLayout'], 
    function ($,_,Backbone,Marionette,Routes,appModel,appLayout) {
    "use strict";

    socialApp = window.socialApp || {}; // i am declared the socialApp here.
    socialApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    socialApp.addInitializer(function(options) {
        socialApp.NewRoute = new Routes;
        socialApp.GenModel = new appModel({router:socialApp.NewRoute}); //i am getting error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: socialApp is not defined" - why?
        socialApp.Layout = new appLayout();
        socialApp.Layout.render();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

It is not happening always, but some instance i am getting this error. how to resolve this?

in the `appModel` i declared like this :

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','marionette'], 
    function ($,_,Backbone,Marionette) {
    "use strict";
    socialApp = window.socialApp || {}; //exactly i am getting error from here on refresh some times..
    socialApp.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(currentRoute){
            this.router = currentRoute.router;
        }
    });
    return socialApp.Model;
});
```

Where i do the mistake? any one figure out me please?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare global variable within an AMD module like that, socialApp is a local variable within the module itself. So either declare an AMD module for your socialApp variable like this:

`File: socialApp.js`

```
define(['marionette'], function(Marionette) {
   var socialApp = {};
   return socialApp;
});
```

And require socialApp from everywhere you use it.

`File: appModel.js`

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','marionette', 'socialApp'], 
    function ($,_,Backbone,Marionette, socialApp) {

    socialApp.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(currentRoute){
            this.router = currentRoute.router;
        }
    });
    return socialApp.Model;
});
```

Or, if you insist on global variables; declare socialApp within window explicitly.

replace `socialApp = window.socialApp || {};` with `window.socialApp = window.socialApp || {};`.

Comment: I think, need to declare in module. it's not working as `window.socialApp` - even.